# Using the MetadataExtractor library in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, metadata-extractor

I'm trying to use [this metadata extractor dll](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet) in Powershell. I've used .net dlls in Powershell before, but I just don't get this working.

```
$assembly = [reflection.assembly]::loadfile( "$PSScriptRoot\MetadataExtractor.dll")
#$directory = New-Object -TypeName ImageMetadataReader
#$directory = New-Object ImageMetadataReader::ReadMetadata -ArgumentList $path
#$directory = New-Object -TypeName [ImageMetadataReader]::ReadMetadata -ArgumentList $path
```

No matter how I try to call the dll, all I get is some version of

> ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata: The term 'ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

The dll even has some [Powershell functionality](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet/blob/master/MetadataExtractor.PowerShell/ExtractMetadataCmdlet.cs), but trying to use this I get this result:

```
import-module "C:\path\to\MetadataExtractor.dll"
get-module

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                ----------------
Binary     2.4.1.0               MetadataExtractor
```

As you can see, the `ExportedCommands` section is empty, and trying to run the cmdlet (from the source code I assume it should be called `Extract-Metadata`) doesn't work either.

> extract-metadata: The term 'extract-metadata' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

How do I have to call the methods from this dll from Powershell?